# Show complete files as they would exist in the git index

Tags: git

I'm writing a pre-commit hook, and would like to do a check on the entire contents of each file that's about to be committed (specifically a lint check on the files).  I want to lint check the file as it's going to be commited, not as it exists in my working tree (which may differ).

The pre-commit hook example that comes with git shows you how to get the diff (so you can examine for spaces and such), but I need to get the entire file as it's going to be committed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/checkout-area checkout-index path/to/file-to-checkout
```

The `--work-tree` option tells git to use a different area as the work tree, so that you don't overwrite the file in your true work-tree. You might also want to add the `-f` option to tell it to overwrite if necessary, but if your script properly cleans up after itself it shouldn't be necessary. See the [man page for checkout-index](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html) for more information.

Comment: Yep, checkout-index was just the hint I needed to find what I needed to find.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for a **single**<sup>1</sup> file is (assuming that you are not during conflicted merge or rebase):

```
$ git show :0:path/to/file
```

(where `path/to/file` is relative to top directory in repository).

Or "`git cat-file blob :0:path/to/file`", which (I think) wouldn't invoke any filters (keyword expansion, end of line conversion, etc.).

See section about extended sha-1 syntax in [git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) manpage

---

<sup>1.)</sup> the advantage of [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342764/show-complete-files-as-they-would-exist-in-the-git-index/1342846#1342846) is that using `git checkout-index` you can checkout more than one file; you can checkout whole directory or even whole project.

Comment: This is pretty awesome though I'm gonna find an excuse to use it.

Comment: The shorthand seems to be `git show :path/to/file` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475234/3795597). I use it to check if no API key was staged in a pre-commit hook.

Comment: -1 unfortunately using `git show` in this way gives you just the staged diff of the file, not the whole staged file, which is what OP wanted.