# How can I run git pre-commit checks only on staged content?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Suppose `git status` gives this:

```
# On branch X
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file1.cc
#   modified:   file1.h
#   modified:   file1_test.cc
#   modified:   SConscript
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   file1.cc
#   modified:   tinyxml2 (untracked content)
#
```

In this case, **only some of the changes made to file1.cc have been staged**/indexed for the next commit.

I run a pre-commit script to do run a style checker:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                     

git stash -q --keep-index

# Do the checks                                                                                                                                                                 
RESULT=0
while read status file
do
    if python ~/python/cpplint.py "$file"; then
        let RESULT=1
    fi
done < <(git diff --cached --name-status --diff-filter=ACM | grep -P  '\.((cc)|(h)|(cpp)|(c))$' )

git stash pop -q

[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

As suggested by [here](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/), I stash unstaged files before I run my style checks, and pop them afterwards. However, in the case where only some of the changes in a file were staged, this causes a merge conflict when I pop the stash at the end of the pre-commit hook.

What is a better way to do this? I want to run a style check against the staged version of the files about to be committed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show complete files as they would exist in the git index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342764/show-complete-files-as-they-would-exist-in-the-git-index)

Comment: I think the accepted answer there is better for my purposes than any here (I'm trying to pass the files to a few different style checkers).

Answer (score 10):

I'd avoid using `git stash` automatically in hooks. I found that it is possible to use `git show ':filename'` to get contents of stashed file.
Instead I used next approach:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR | while read filename; do
    git show ":$filename" | GIT_VERIFY_FILENAME="$filename" verify_copyright \
        || exit $?
done \
    || exit $?
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace `git stash -q --keep-index` with:

```
git diff --full-index --binary > /tmp/stash.$$
git stash -q --keep-index
```

...and `git stash pop -q` with:

```
git apply --whitespace=nowarn < /tmp/stash.$$` && git stash drop -q
rm /tmp/stash.$$
```

This will save the diff to a temporary file and reapply it using `git apply` at the end. The changes are still redundantly saved to the stash (which is later dropped), so that if something goes wrong with the reapplying, you can inspect them using `git stash show -p` without having to look for the temp file.

Answer (score 2):

### How to gate commits without stashing

We use this `.git/hooks/pre-commit` for checking an atom syntax package

#### Key bits

1. `git checkout-index -a --prefix={{temp_dir}}`

It may/may not be far slower/take more space than stashing, but automation which messes with the index seems inherently brittle. Perhaps there needs to be a git contrib script which makes a soft-/hard-link tree, minimum space read-only, temporary index checkout, facilitating better/faster `.git/hooks/pre-commit` (or, say, `.git/hooks/pre-commit-index`) scripts so that a full second copy of the working dir isn't needed, just the working-dir->index changes.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'tmpdir'
autoload :FileUtils,  'fileutils'
autoload :Open3,      'open3'
autoload :Shellwords, 'shellwords'

# ---- setup

INTERACTIVE         = $stdout.tty? || $stderr.tty?
DOT                 = -'.'
BLOCK_SIZE          = 4096
TEMP_INDEX_DIR      = Dir.mktmpdir
TEMP_INDEX_DIR_REAL = File.realpath(TEMP_INDEX_DIR)

def cleanup
  FileUtils.remove_entry(TEMP_INDEX_DIR) if File.exist? TEMP_INDEX_DIR
end

at_exit { cleanup }

%w[INT TERM PIPE HUP QUIT].each do |sig|
  Signal.trap(sig) { cleanup }
end

# ---- functions

def fix_up_dir_output(data)
  data.gsub! TEMP_INDEX_DIR_REAL, DOT
  data.gsub! TEMP_INDEX_DIR, DOT
  data
end

def sh(*args)
  Open3.popen3(*args) do |_, stdout, stderr, w_thr|
    files = [stdout, stderr]
    until files.empty? do
      if ready = IO.select(files)
        ready[0].each do |f|
          begin
            data = f.read_nonblock BLOCK_SIZE
            data = fix_up_dir_output data
            if f.fileno == stderr.fileno
              $stderr.write data
            else
              $stdout.write data
            end
          rescue EOFError
            files.delete f
          end
        end
      end
    end
    if !(done = w_thr.value).success?
      exit(done.exitstatus)
    end
  end
end

def flags(args)
  skip = false
  r = []
  args.each do |a|
    if a[0] == '-' && !skip
      a.slice! 0
      if a[0] == '-'
        skip ||= a[1].nil?
        a.slice! 0
        r << a unless a.empty?
      else # -[^-]+
        r += a.split ''
      end
    end
  end
  r
end

def less_lint
  args = %w[lessc --lint]
  args << '--no-color' unless INTERACTIVE
  args << 'index.less'
  sh(*args)
end

def ensure_git_commit_signed
  pcmd = `ps -wwp#{Process.ppid} -ocommand=`.chop
  args = flags(Shellwords.split(pcmd)[1..-1])
  return unless (args & %w[gpg-sign S]).empty?
  $stderr.puts 'All git commits must be GPG-signed'
  $stderr.puts "    command: #{pcmd}"
  exit 1
end

# ---- main

# 1. make sure all commits are signed
ensure_git_commit_signed

# 2. check files that are in the index
sh 'git', 'checkout-index', '-a', "--prefix=#{TEMP_INDEX_DIR}/"
Dir.chdir TEMP_INDEX_DIR do
  # 3. make sure all commits contain only legal .less files
  less_lint
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @ony's answer with support for things like Spotless

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
./mvnw -T1C -q -B spotless:apply
if IFS=$'\n' changes=($(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR))
then
  git add -u "${changes[@]}"
fi
```

This will run the files that you need and add the changed ones.